# Does SQL query structure have an impact its performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My question is theoretical. Say the following query (option A):

```
Select *
from orders o
  inner join (
     select *
     from orderDetails 
     where product = 'shirt'
              ) od    on o.orderId = od.orderId
```

Versus the following (option B)

```
Select *
from orders o
  inner join orderDetails  od    on o.orderId = od.orderId
where od.product = 'shirt'
```

Is there any technical advantage of one over the other? For example, I get the impression that option A is less resource demanding on the DB since the inner join occurs on a already narrowed down number of rows. Whereas, option B gives the same result, however, it seems to perform the inner join on all the orderIds available before narrowing it down to the shirts.

I'm curious about the end impact bc, at times stored procedures get quite large, and I'd like to ensure that they don't affect report loading time needlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two queries should evaluate to exactly the same execution plan in SQL Server -- same performance.  This is regardless of indexes.

Why?  SQL is a *descriptive* language.  A `SELECT` query *describes* the result set.  It does not specify how the result set is created.  In most databases, the work of figuring out what to do is handled by the SQL compiler and optimizer, which produce a directed-acyclic graph (DAG) of operations (some databases also do run-time optimizations).  To the newcomer, the operations in the DAG look nothing like the original `SELECT`.

Not all databases have optimizers as smart as SQL Server.  For instance, there is a difference in MySQL -- particularly in older versions.  MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries, which usually adversely affect performance.  However, that is due to a poor optimizing strategy rather than to SQL in general.